# navbarPage + css.file in Shiny

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I would like to use css.file in Shiny app in `NavbarPage` style. I write

```
shinyUI(
  navbarPage("Title",
             theme = "bootstrap.css",
             tabPanel("tabPanel1"),
             tabPanel("tabPanel2"),
             tabPanel("tabPanel3")
...
```

But it does not look nice (`tabPanel` name are positioned in  vertical order not in horizontal).It works all the time in all bootstrap.css file I choose. It is possible to change it in normal (horizontal) order?

[image: vertical]

**Update**

I found this [proposition](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/uf2acgqF45k/LC7lAL4nFFIJ) but it does not work at all.

Comment: @ cdeterman Hi, sorry to bother you but do you know to figure it out?

Comment: can you post a link/the code  for the `bootstrap.css` you want to use?

Comment: @NicE https://gist.github.com/Nicolabo/6d53c896c978287da563

Comment: I think, this link has an answer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/6C9SbSLbKmc . The workaround is to use header tag, not theme. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try running a report with `theme = ""` you will realize that you are simply not loading your css file.

```
runApp(
  list(
    ui = navbarPage(theme="",
                    "Title",
                    tabPanel("tabPanel1"),
                    tabPanel("tabPanel2"),
                    tabPanel("tabPanel3")),
    server = function(input, output){

    }
    )
)
```

I'm not sure if there is a bug with `navbarPage` with the `theme` but if you `includeCSS` manually, then you will notice that it is loaded.  You can try with my [gist](https://gist.github.com/cdeterman/8e9fb019e5100fc5cd15).  Note, the format still doesn't appear ideal but at least the css file is loaded.

```
https://gist.github.com/cdeterman/8e9fb019e5100fc5cd15
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Shiny app, Can you apply `float:left` to that 3 panels in css? 
By parent class or direct.